# Report download not prompting user to save

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jasper-reports

I'm trying to generate a simple PDF report using JasperReport on a button click. Here's the relevant code:

report.xhtml:

`<p:commandButton value="#{msg['report.generate']}" action="#{generateReportBean.generateReport}" />`

GenerateReportBean.java:

```
public void generateReport() throws JRException, IOException {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext
            .getResponse();

    InputStream reportStream = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/reports/report.jrxml");
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(reportStream);
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
    byte[] report = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jasperReport, new HashMap(), new JREmptyDataSource());

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(report.length);
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.pdf" );

    ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    servletOutputStream.write(report);
    servletOutputStream.flush();
    servletOutputStream.close();
    facesContext.responseComplete();

}
```

The problem is that when I use FireBug I can see a response (for me it's ok):

```
X-Powered-By    JSF/2.0
Content-Type    application/pdf
Content-Length  1310
Content-Disposition attachment; filename=report.pdf
Server  Jetty(7.4.0.v20110414)
```

But I don't get the popup that would allow me to save the pdf. As you can see I'm developing on Jetty 7.4 maven plugin. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add ajax="false" to your commandButton

```
<p:commandButton ajax="false" value="#{msg['report.generate']}" action="#{generateReportBean.generateReport}" />
```