# JSF 2.0 Open PDF Report (not save)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jasper-reports

I am using *PrimeFaces*.

I have one data table contain with command link pdf generate

When I click on this link I want to open *pdf* in new browser.

My code for generation report as *PDF*:

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
String reportPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/report/personReport.jrxml");
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(reportPath);
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

ArrayList<PersonReportBean> arrayList = new ArrayList<PersonReportBean>();
arrayList.add(bean); // here bean populate with all data
JRBeanCollectionDataSource collectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(arrayList);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap<String, Object>(), collectionDataSource);
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, response.getOutputStream());
exporter.exportReport();
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

Comment: You can read [Report download not prompting user to save](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085049/report-download-not-prompting-user-to-save) post on SO

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint,response.getOutputStream());
```

instead of:

```
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();   
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, response.getOutputStream());   
exporter.exportReport();
```